# How to compile all C files in multiple sub-directories without using wildcards in a Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a program that needs multiple files to compile, what I need here is how to make the next code shorter:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/Route/%.c
    @cc -c $< -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$(notdir $@)
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/Handlers/%.c
    @cc -c $< -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$(notdir $@)
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/Helpers/%.c
    @cc -c $< -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$(notdir $@)
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/Core/%.c
    @cc -c $< -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$(notdir $@)
```

Using wildcards is prohibited in this exercise, so I am looking for another way to make this Makefile more simple.

Comment: "Using wildcards is prohibited in this exercise" - why? Is the whole point of the exercise to learn how to write makefiles by hand _without_ using wildcards, or is that just a restriction unrelated to your _actual_ exercise?

Comment: @Dai Exactly!
This is the whole point from this exercise, I have been looking around for some alternative but I haven't find anything yet.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is `@cc` always the same compiler (e.g. `gcc`, etc?), if so there might be compiler-specific flags that do what you want.

Comment: @Dai Yes it is, we are compiling our programs using `cc` rather than `gcc`.

Comment: `cc` isn't a program though, it's an alias for the _actual_ system default C compiler, which I assume is `gcc` in your case (unless you're running something relatively exotic like HP-UX...?)

Comment: @Dai I guess you are right, so is there a way to make the Makefile more simpler?

Comment: I'unno, run `man make` and see what it suggests?

Comment: I am looking right now, Thanks man!!

Comment: Indeed, thanks `man` very much so ;)

Comment: Try `VPATH` or `vpath`.

Comment: Better than the man page is the GNU make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html  VPATH is the right answer here.  But, note that your use of `$(OBJ_DIR)/$(notdir $@)` in your recipes is not good.  Your recipe must always build `$@` exactly (I think it will anyway but why add all the extra trouble?)